# Injection of new properties to a class with variable names using Postsharp or other injection library

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nunit, postsharp, reflection.emit

***TLDR: is it possible, and if so, how, to inject or copy-then-rename methods in .NET projects using some injection mechanism?***

---

Somehow I thought this was simple enough to do, I guess I never had a need for it earlier. The use-case is this: NUnit allows to augment a test method with a `TestSource` attribute, which takes a property or field as a fixed name. This creates multiple test cases for each item in the enumeration.

The problem arises when the items are class instances and you want to use that collection on multiple test cases. When two tests end up having the same name, the second (or first?) one will not end up in NUnit runners because they will share the same name. You can either:

- Create a separate property for the same collection that only differs in returned test name
- Not set the test name at all (which generates some rather unreadable test names)

Ideally I would want to append to the test name.

### Method 1, set name

```
public class TC
{
    public int Id;
    public Guid guid;
    public string name;
}

internal static TestCaseData[] CreateTestOrders
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 123, guid = new Guid("73C9B241-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "John" })
            .SetName("123"),
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 456, guid = new Guid("01020304-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Anton" })
            .SetName("456"),
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 789, guid = new Guid("02040608-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Josh" })
            .SetName("789"),
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 036, guid = new Guid("12131415-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Jonathan" })
            .SetName("036")

        };
    }
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("CreateTestOrders")]
public void TestOrderId(TC tc)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(123, tc.Id);
}

[Test, TestCaseSource("CreateTestOrders")]
public void TestOrderPersonDetails(TC tc)
{
    Assert.Contains(tc.name, new[] { "John", "Anton", "Josh" });
}
```

The first `TestOrderId` creates tests 036, 123, 456, 789. The second creates these as well, because NUnit does not prepend the actual test case name to it, which drops them from certain tools because the test name is no longer unique.

### Method 2, let NUnit choose a name

Let's change the source to this:

```
internal static TestCaseData[] CreateTestOrders
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 123, guid = new Guid("73C9B241-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "John" })
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 456, guid = new Guid("01020304-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Anton" })
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 789, guid = new Guid("02040608-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Josh" })
            new TestCaseData(new TC { Id = 036, guid = new Guid("12131415-11C3-4DBD-9EB8-E7BDE7A2D8DD"), name = "Jonathan" })

        };
    }
}
```

Now I end up with eight tests with the same name. Some tools will show one, others 2 (one for each test method name), others 8 of the same name.

### Any thoughts?

Neither are ideal, either way you end up with non-unique and less-then descriptive test names, and above that, with a lot of such tests to be written it gets rather tedious. It is not possible (as far as I can tell) to pass the method name to the test case generator.

I tried my luck with PostSharp, that I happened lying around from another project. Since it is so trivial to inject methods with the framework. But as far as I can tell, it is *not possible* to inject a method with different names.

Since NUnit uses reflection, and does not recognize `dynamic` types, using an override on a TryMethodCall didn't appear to work either.

I'll probably survive without a solution, or create a pull request on NUnit, but apart from that, it still left me wondering, is it really that hard to (statically or dynamically) inject a method or property?

Comment: What is the test runner that you are using?

Comment: @yacoub, different ones. Nunit's own runner occasionally, for continuous tdd usually ncrunch and for CI testing teamcity. Other programmers in the team may use other tools. But uniqueness of test names is good practice...

Comment: I ask the question to NCrunch and apparently, it is a [known problem with NCrunch](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postst1704_Losing-many-tests-due-to-duplicates-in-test-names--but-not-method-names.aspx) and possibly, a [solution may be on its way](http://forum.ncrunch.net/yaf_postsm7896_Sharing-test-case-source-between-tests.aspx#post7896). Nevertheless, with all the PostSharp, CInject and Castle on this world, I'd be surprised if it isn't possible.